# How to get custom date [only YYYY] validated MVC razor?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, datetime, razor

I'm having a problem with dateTime. I want date to be displayed as "YYYY". It works fine in index view, but doesn't do a proper job in Edit and Create views [The input format has to be dd/mm/yyyy]. Plus, the validations doesn't switch to my custom error message.

Code in my model class:

```
[Display(Name = "Created")]
[DataType(DataType.Date, ErrorMessage="The date should be in a year format like 2000, or 12/12/2000")]
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy}")]
public object dateCreation { get; set; }
```

Code in my Index view which works just fine showing just the year

```
 @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.dateCreation)
```

Code in my Create view which doesn't seem to work (how ever, he shows me a placeholder) and gives me custom error

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.dateCreation, "{0:yyyy}", new { @placeholder = "2014"})

 @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.dateCreation)
```